# Vuejs no me reconoce componente tras crearlo con 'vue generate component'

Tags: vue.js

He creado mi componente `menu` de esta manera :

```
vgc components/nav
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En `src/App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app mt-0 ">
    <menu></menu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import  menu from './components/'

  export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    menu //Esta subrayado en rojo, dice que no esta siendo usado.
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

En mi fichero `main.js`

```
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)


new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Me da este error, me dice que no se esta usando pero como veis tengo el component ahi:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

...\PROYECTOS\VUEJS\to_do_list_front\src\App.vue
  14:5  error  The "menu" component has been registered but not used  vue/no-unused-components

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Es que no lo estas llamando en esta parte "import  menu from './components/'" te esta faltando la ruta del archivo porque unicamente lo estas llamando a la carpeta components seria import  menu from './components/index.vue
'

Comment: y no se si estes utilizando vue 3 pero unicamente se añadiria al template de esta manera <menu />